# macOS equivalent of `cmdtool`

Tags: terminal, command-line, logs, console

I recently saw someone on a Unix system run the command

`cmdtool <some_log_file.log>`

and the terminal showed a logging window that live-updated as text was entered into the log file. (I'm probably missing some arguments there.)

Is there a Mac OS equivalent to get this behavior?

See [*cmdtool* on Ubuntu man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cmdtool.1.html).

Comment: this seems to be specific to Sun/Solaris boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`tail`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tail.1.html) command to see live output of a textual log file:

```
tail -f <some_log_file.log
```

`tail` does not open a new Terminal.app window, but this could be [achieved with AppleScript or Automator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975239/applescript-to-open-terminal-run-command-and-show-not-working).

Comment: Clarified my question - this is exactly the command I was looking for, no need to "pop up" a new window.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an application, Console will do this. It's not restricted to just the log files it knows about, you can open any file.